# Useless jp / jnp assembly instruction on x86_64

Tags: c, assembly, llvm, x86-64, instructions

I'm trying to figure out what purpose `jp`/`jnp` instructions serve in LLVM-generated C code. Sample:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double value = 1.5;

    if (value == 1.5) {
        value = 3.0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assembly output:

```
Ltmp4:
    movsd   LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
Ltmp5:
    movsd   %xmm0, -24(%rbp)
Ltmp6:
    movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm1
    ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm1
    jne LBB0_2
    jp  LBB0_2
## BB#1:
    movabsq $3, %rax
    cvtsi2sdq   %rax, %xmm0
Ltmp7:
    movsd   %xmm0, -24(%rbp)
Ltmp8:
LBB0_2:
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

The `jne` is checking if `value != 1.5` and jumping over the assignment, but what is the `jp` doing in this context?

Comment: I think you told llvm not to make optimized code, or something.  There's no way a compiler would ever emit `mov $0, %eax` instead of `xor %eax, %eax` with any level of optimization.  There's other nasty stuff in that code:  `movabsq $3, %rax` is 10 bytes, compared to `movl $3, %eax`, but has a completely identical effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`jne` is `jump if not equal`, i.e. jump if the zero flag is not set. `jp` is `jump if parity`.

`ucomisd` is defined to compare two `doubles`. It will indicate that they are one of four things: unordered, equal, greater than or less than.

The zero flag is set if the numbers are unordered or equal. So the `jne` avoids the remaining cases of greater than or less than.

Parity is set only if the result is unordered. The `jp` catches that.

So the two together avoid: unordered, greater than, less than. Leaving only the fourth possibility, of equal.

Comment: A note on terminology: "Unordered" means that the two arguments have no relaitve order; that is, that at least one of them is a NaN. If they are non-NaNs and equal, that is not the same is "unordered".

Comment: That means, however, that the `jne` catches the case of the numbers being unequal, and the `jp` catches the case of them being unordered. These are different cases, and not redundant.

Comment: @Dolda2000 indeed; a failure of terminology here. It's all three flags set for unordered.

Comment: So to confirm, there are two scenarios where a jump to `LBB0_2` would occur: 1) `value != 1.5` 2) `value` and `1.5` being unordered (e.g. `value` being a NaN)

Comment: @Tommy sorry to nitpick, but I disagree that the `jp` is redundant. And after experimenting with `-Os` and `-O3`, I see no evidence to support your claim that it's optimized out.

Comment: @user3386109 can you tell me on what occasion parity will be set but zero will not be set? `jp` will be effective only if the result of the comparison is 'unordered'. 'Unordered' also sets zero. I'll put what LLVM is generating into my answer as it won't fit here.

Comment: My understanding is that `ucomisd` signals that two numbers are equal by setting `ZF=1` and `PF=0`. If both flags are `1`, then that indicates that one or both of the numbers are `NAN`. You can ignore the `PF` only if you know that neither input to `ucomisd` is `NAN`.  Note: I didn't try the "unsafe math optimization" option, that may remove the check for `PF`.

Comment: @user3386109 on further inspection, you're right and I was wrong. Answer heavily revised and marked as community wiki to record that it'd be inaccurate to call me the sole owner of it (and, for the record, my optimised code test's attempt to prevent the conditional from being optimised out was flawed).

Comment: @Tommy Cheers, you have my respect as colleague and scientist, for the scientist seeks only true knowledge, whereas the politician seeks only to hide mistakes.